# Final Grades Program = doesn't print the actual list (Display their letter grade for each person)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying create a program that will:
Prompt the user for the number of grades that will be entered
Take in the users name, and then their grade in two prompts
Display their letter grade for each person
Then calculate the class average, highest mark, and lowest mark from the input

What it should look like:

```
Welcome to the Final Grades Program

Enter the number of students: 2

Student's name: paige
Student's mark (%): 89

Student's name: mitzy
Student's mark (%): 78

Paige             A
Mitzy             B
```

however when I press F5 it doesn't print the actual list (Display their letter grade for each person) and I have no idea why or what I'm doing wrong. This is what I have:

```
import bisect

def grading():
    if int(stuMark) > 80:
        print ("A")
        print ()

    elif int(stuMark) > 70 and int(stuMark) < 79:
        print ("B")
        print ()

    elif int(stuMark) > 60 and int(stuMark) < 69:
        print ("C")
        print ()

    elif int(stuMark) > 50 and int(stuMark) < 59:
        print ("D")
        print ()
         
    elif int(stuMark) < 50:
       print ("F")
       print ()

def intro():
    students = []
    marks = []

    while True:
        # Number of students
        numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")
        print ()

        #Info (Name/grade)
        for x in range(int(numStudents)):
            name = input("Student's name: ")
            mark = int(input("Student's mark (%): "))
            print ()
            students.append(name)
            marks.append(mark)

def class_list():
    name = []
    mark = []

    print ()
    print("Student Name \t\t Student Grade")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    for x in range(len(name)):
        print(f"{name[x]} \t\t\t {mark[x]}")


def main():
    print ("Welcome to the Final Grades Program")
    print()
    intro()
    class_list()

main()
```

Comment: I have two things to ask can you share your actual output and why dont you call the grading function anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is with the scope of your variables. Your name, students and marks list should be global variables defines at the start of the program.The next problem is that the `students` and `name` lists serve the same purpose and should be unified. Your last two problems are, that you do not get the grades as letters because you do not call the `grading` function, and you have an unnecessary loop when asking for inputs that continues until the program is broken and never proceeds to outputting the grades

**Here is the fixed code:**

```
#Your global variables
marks = []
students = []

def grading(stuMark):
    if int(stuMark) > 80:
        return ("A")

    elif int(stuMark) > 70 and int(stuMark) < 79:
        return ("B")

    elif int(stuMark) > 60 and int(stuMark) < 69:
        return ("C")

    elif int(stuMark) > 50 and int(stuMark) < 59:
        return ("D")
         
    elif int(stuMark) < 50:
        return ("F")

    
def intro():

    # Number of students
    numStudents = input("Enter the number of students: ")
    print ()

    #Info (Name/grade)
    for x in range(int(numStudents)):
        name = input("Student's name: ")
        mark = int(input("Student's mark (%): "))
        print ()
        students.append(name)
        marks.append(mark)

def class_list():


    print ()
    print("Student Name \t\t Student Grade")
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    for x in range(len(students)):
        print(f"{students[x]} \t\t\t {grading(marks[x])}")


def main():
    print ("Welcome to the Final Grades Program")
    print()
    intro()
    class_list()

main()
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to the Final Grades Program

Enter the number of students: 2

Student's name: paige
Student's mark (%): 89

Student's name: mitzy
Student's mark (%): 78


Student Name             Student Grade
---------------------------------------------
paige                    A
mitzy                    B
```

Comment: You also dont need bisect so I removed it